# What is the importance and effect of the smoothness of a spline?

Tags: continuity, numerical-methods, interpolation, spline, smooth-functions

A Catmull-Rom spline is a $C^1$ (but not $C^2$) function, that is, its first derivative is continuous (but its second derivative might not be). However, there are splines that have $C^2$ or, in general, $C^k$ continuity.

In practice, for the purpose of interpolation, what is the difference between a $C^1$ spline (like the Catmull-Rom spline) as opposed to a $C^2$ spline? Why is the smoothness really important? How does it affect the modeling or interpolation? So, how do I determine if I need a $C^1$ or $C^2$ or, in general, $C^k$ spline as opposed to any other spline?

Answer (score 1):

Whether to use a $C^1$ or a $C^2$ spline for your interpolation really depends on how you will use that interpolated spline in your application.

For example, if your interpolated spline is an approximation to a $C^2$ continuous function, naturally you will use a $C^2$ spline to interpolate.

In the area of geometric modeling, surfaces are often constructed from curves using technique such as lofting or sweeping. Having a $C^2$ continuous curve is the minimum requirement to achieve a $C^2$ continuous surface, which will have better aesthetic appearance than a surface that is just $C^1$ continuous.

Please note that to achieve a $C^2$ continuous spline interpolation, you do not need to use quintic splines. Cubic splines (e.g. a cubic B-spline curve) can still be $C^2$ continuous.

Comment: You say "if your interpolated spline is supposed to be an approximation to a $C^2$ continuous function", but why should it be supposed? Is it only aesthetics, do $C^2$ functions really look "better" than $C^1$ functions? Are there other reasons for using $C^2$ as opposed than $C^1$?

Comment: I think this is a wording issue. What I meant is "If you want to approximate a C2 continuous function using an interpolated spline,.....".  I will revise my wording.  As for other reasons for using C2 splines, aesthetic appearance is one of them. The other might include engineering concerns such as fluid dynamic behavior,...etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give an example: Recently, I had a pointset $\{x_i, y_i\}$ which came from discretization of second order ODE $y'' + p(x)y' + q(x)y = f$. Then I wanted a continuous representation of the pointset, so I created a spline interpolant $s$ out of it. Now what is the error of the interpolant? You compute
$$
\left\| s'' + ps' + qs - f\right\|
$$

Ok, so I needed at least a $C^{2}$ spline, otherwise I can't compute $s''$. Turns out, this was bad, because if I only used a $C^2$ spline, I just had line segments between interpolation points, and those line segments said my error was worse than it really was. So I used a quintic spline, whose second derivative is a cubic spline, which gave me a really nice approximation of $s''$ to $u''$.

So that's an example! There are a million reasons why you'd choose differing level of smoothness in practice.

Comment: Where does that error come from? From the definition of the ODE?

Comment: No, the error came from using a numerical method to solve the ODE, so the pointset has some error.

Comment: Ok. You say "I just had line segments between interpolation points, and those line segments said my error was worse than it really was". Can you elaborate? Why do you end up only with line segments between interpolation points?

Comment: The second derivative of a cubic polynomial is a linear polynomial.

Comment: Yes, but why do you care about the second derivative (apart from calculating the error)? I don't see the relationship between "I just had line segments between interpolation points" (which I assume that you mean that the interpolating points are connected by a line segment because of the choice of a $C^2$ spline, even though I don't understand _why_?) and the fact that you need the second derivative of the spline.

Comment: The actual solution is $C^{\infty}$ and so its second derivative is $C^{\infty}$. Then I approximate the second derivative by piecewise linear segments, which has large error.

Comment: I only care about the second derivative to calculate the error.

Comment: So, to clarify, you only needed the spline to have a certain degree of smoothness because you needed to calculate the $k$the derivative of this spline in order to understand the evolution of some error metric?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Ok. Once, I also needed to calculate the curvature of a CR spline, so I also needed the second derivative. However, I was looking for an answer that gives some insight into the advantages of the smoothness of the spline with respect to the shape of the spline itself.

Comment: Sometimes you get a higher order of approximation with a higher order spline, so you can use less memory. Then again, evaluation takes more time.